# Customize "searchable" Search field SwiftUI iOS 15

Tags: swift, search, swiftui, uisearchbar

When using the new `.searchable()` modifier in SwiftUI on iOS 15 I have no way to customize the Search Bar appearance. Specifically, I wan't it to look good with the color I'm using for my Navigation Bar.[image]

I tried altering the `.appearance()`  like this.

```swift
UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
```

But only managed to get this.

[image]

Even though this kind of succeeded the spacing does not look good. I would rather tint it white.

Comment: Could you provide some additional code. E.g., The code in the `ContentView`? This is because by adding the `searchable()` modifier, the `TextField` is transparent

Comment: You could implement the init() function to initialize these attributes. It actually works for me when I use UINavigationBar.appearnce() to change the tintColor. But I am still learning how to change the textColor.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by using these two global appearance lines.

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .white
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .black
```

[image]

Comment: For me it seems like the tintColor has no effect. Have you tried to set the color to anything but black?

Answer (score 5):

iOS 16, I did this:

```
    UISearchBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setImage(<your search image, e.g., magnifyingGlassImage>, for: .search, state: .normal)
    UISearchBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setImage(<your clear image, e.g., closeImage>, for: .clear, state: .normal)
    UISearchBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = <Color.yourTintColor>
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = <Color.yourBackgroundColor>
    UISearchTextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: <your promptText, e.g., "Search", attributes: [.foregroundColor: <Color.yourForegroundColor>])
```

Comment: It must be the accepted answer in 2023!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in iOS 17, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77957654/searchbar-is-always-slightly-darker-or-brighter-as-the-defined-background

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but you could try overriding only the search bar's color scheme / interface style to Dark:

```swift
UISearchBar.appearance().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

This way, the rest of the navigation bar and app should remain unaffected.

Answer (score -1):

The textColor of the input field can be changed from black to white by altering the `.preferredColorScheme()` of the view to which the `.searchable` modifier is applied. Setting `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` will set the color to white.

Comment: This will also change the colour of the notification bar (time, battery, coverage, etc), so I wouldn't say it would be a valid solution, since the goal is to change the text colour of the search bar

Comment: I added an answer that takes this into account and only changes the color scheme (interface style) of the search bar itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75649611/8538539

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `.font` and `.foregroundColor` modifiers after `.searchable` will do the desired result, but it still doesn't work with `.background` modifier as the time of this writing (iOS 16).