# Set background color for navbar on iOS

Tags: swiftui, navbar

Using this
[Customize "searchable" Search field SwiftUI iOS 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511960/customize-searchable-search-field-swiftui-ios-15)
and other suggestions

I've tried this

```
public var body: some View {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        return navbody
        .toolbarBackground(Color("backgroundPaper", bundle: sharedBundle))
    } else {
        return navbody
    }
}
```

but I get excellent diagnostics from swift compiler "exited with non zero code".
Is there a way out of this predicament?

```
var navbody: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color("backgroundPaper", bundle: sharedBundle)
            List(...
}}}
```

Comment: Those UITableView lines don’t belong in the body. Try init

Comment: moved. Same compiler crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the code inside an init() inside your view struct. I can confirm this works perfectly on iOS 16

Like this:

```
struct SearchView: View {

    init() {
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make the background behind Search transparent? I need to make the navigation bar transparent: the parent of UISearchBar that is