# SearchBar is always slightly darker (or brighter) as the defined background

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to set the color of a SearchBar in my NavigationStack:

```
NavigationStack {
   ...
}.searchable(text: $events.searchText, isPresented: $searchIsActive)
```

That's how it looks default:

[image]

When I set `UISearchTextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.white`, I get a search bar with the color `#DEDEE1`. If I set it to black, it gets `#1C1C1F`. It seems that there is some kind of "tint" which I need to remove?

[image]

## Update 1

Looking at the View Hierarchy Debugger, there is a `_UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView` which seems to cause this effect. The description reveals that it has `tertiarySystemFillColor` applied as background. But I have absolutely no clue how to get rid of this:

[image]

## Update 2

I got it working, but I would not call it a solution ... while I'm able to set the background color with `UISearchTextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .white`, the `tertiarySystemFillColor` does not go away. But I found a hack to do this:

```
SomeView {
}.introspect(.searchField , on: .iOS(.v17)) { searchField in
  // set background color
  searchField.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white

  // removing the border style also removes the `tertiarySystemFillColor`
  searchField.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none

  // but removing the border style also removes the corner radius, so we have to apply it back
  searchField.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

That fixed the issue for me. I thought that I may be able to set this like I set the background color also, but this does not work:

```
UISearchTextField.appearance().borderStyle = .none
UISearchTextField.appearance().layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Anyway, looking at the Vier Hierarchy Debugger again, the extra layer is removed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 15, SwiftUI provides new ways to customize the appearance of views directly within the SwiftUI framework using modifiers

```
       .onAppear {

                let searchBarAppearance = UISearchBar.appearance()
                searchBarAppearance.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 222/255, green: 222/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1)
                searchBarAppearance.tintColor = UIColor(red: 28/255, green: 28/255, blue: 31/255, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not do anything for me 

Comment: Share example code. I will help you with the solution.

Comment: Did you see the update in my post?

Comment: I only see the extra screenshot.

Comment: Yes, and that extra screenshot shows the problem. I'm able to set the color of the SearchBar, but there is always that extra layer on top, which has tertiarySystemFillColor set.

Comment: It's also explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3255076-tertiarysystemfillcolor
> Use this color to fill large shapes, such as input fields, search bars, or buttons.